How to set alignment of a brand new section
in a software project of mine, on linux, I need to create a special section that needs to be populated with 40 bytes large structures. Then I would like to treat this section as an array.
For that I added this linker script with the -T option:
SECTIONS
{
     /* section for CLI cmd array */
    .CLI_cmd_section : ALIGN(8)
    {
        PROVIDE(__CLI_cmd_start = .);
        KEEP(*(.CLI_cmd*));
       . = ALIGN(8) ;
        PROVIDE(__CLI_cmd_end = .);
    }
}
INSERT AFTER .data;

Though, inspecting with objdump I see that the section is aligned to 32 bytes:
Sections:
Idx Name               Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn  Flags
[...]
 25 .data              00000008  0000000000009000  0000000000009000  00008000  2**3  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 26 .CLI_cmd_section   00000068  0000000000009020  0000000000009020  00008020  2**5  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 27 .bss               00000078  00000000000090a0  00000000000090a0  00008088  2**5  ALLOC
[...]

I thought it might be because some of the adjacent sections have such alignment, but even moving it doesn't change
Sections:
Idx Name               Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn  Flags
[...]
 23 .dynamic           000001f0  0000000000008cf0  0000000000008cf0  00007cf0  2**3  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 24 .CLI_cmd_section   00000068  0000000000008ee0  0000000000008ee0  00007ee0  2**5  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 25 .got               000000a8  0000000000008f48  0000000000008f48  00007f48  2**3  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 26 .data              00000008  0000000000009000  0000000000009000  00008000  2**3  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
[...]

I wanted to try to see what happened to impose a higher alignment (64) and in this case it sets it. So it seems that for some reason right now I can't get below 32 on that section.
this is very annoying, because in the array the compiler considers the entries offset by 40 bytes, while the linker has them offset by 64 bytes.
How should I get my array indexed well, and then impose alignment 8?
Also I would like this section to be READONLY, but if I try to impose it I get a warning on the link which I don't know how "serious" it is:
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccDmg9Dd.o: warning: relocation in read-only section `.CLI_cmd.__CLI_cmd_help'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE

Is there a safe, reliable and "clean" way to impose READONLY the .CLI_cmd_section without having errors/warning from the linker?
EDIT
My map file says:
Memory Configuration

Name             Origin             Length             Attributes
*default*        0x0000000000000000 0xffffffffffffffff

so by default no memory region seems to be defined.
therefore, @giackkk, I don't think I can define a memory region without knowing ORIGIN and LENGTH
EDIT a couple of test done
I started from a simplified situation, with the following source:
testAlign.c:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define CLI_Section_Sym(symbol) __attribute__((used, section(".CLI_cmd." #symbol)))
#define CLI_DECL(var)           static const uint32_t var CLI_Section_Sym(var)

CLI_DECL(a) = 5;
CLI_DECL(b) = 6;
CLI_DECL(c) = 7;

static const uint32_t *array[] = {&a, &b, &c};

int main()
{
    extern const uint32_t __CLI_cmd_start;
    extern const uint32_t __CLI_cmd_end;
    const uint32_t       *CLI_cmd_vett;
    int                   CLI_cmd_vett_len;
    CLI_cmd_vett     = &__CLI_cmd_start;
    CLI_cmd_vett_len = (int)(&__CLI_cmd_end - &__CLI_cmd_start);
    assert((sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array)) == CLI_cmd_vett_len);
    for (int i = 0; i < CLI_cmd_vett_len; i++)
    {
        printf("%d    %p %s %p\n", i, array[i], array[i] == &CLI_cmd_vett[i] ? "==" : "!=", &CLI_cmd_vett[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

and I removed any indication of alignment in my linker script.
SECTIONS
{
     /* section for CLI cmd array */
     .CLI_cmd_section :
    {
        PROVIDE(__CLI_cmd_start = .);
        KEEP(*(.CLI_cmd*));
        PROVIDE(__CLI_cmd_end = .);
    }
}
INSERT AFTER .data;

This example works, in the sense that I get what I want, and it also works by running it
Sections:
Idx Name               Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn  Flags
[...]
 24 .data              00000028  0000000000004000  0000000000004000  00003000  2**4  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 25 .CLI_cmd_section   0000000c  0000000000004028  0000000000004028  00003028  2**2  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 26 .bss               00000004  0000000000004034  0000000000004034  00003034  2**0  ALLOC
[...]

.CLI_cmd_section is automagically READONLY and 4 bytes aligned
I now proceed to make it more complicated to get closer to my scenario:
testAlign1.c:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>

struct cmd_tbl_s
{
    const char *name;                  /* Command Name                 */
    const char *usage;                 /* Usage message                */
    void (*fhelp)(void *);             /* detailed help function       */
    const char *detailed_help;         /* detailed help                */
    int (*cmd)(void *, int, char *[]); /* Implementation function      */
};

typedef struct cmd_tbl_s cmd_tbl_t;

#define CLI_Section_Sym(symbol) __attribute__((used, section(".CLI_cmd." #symbol)))
#define CLI_DECL(var)           static const cmd_tbl_t var CLI_Section_Sym(var)

CLI_DECL(a) = {.name = "a"};
CLI_DECL(b) = {.name = "b"};
CLI_DECL(c) = {.name = "c"};

static const cmd_tbl_t *array[] = {&a, &b, &c};

int main()
{
    extern const cmd_tbl_t __CLI_cmd_start;
    extern const cmd_tbl_t __CLI_cmd_end;
    const cmd_tbl_t       *CLI_cmd_vett;
    int                    CLI_cmd_vett_len;
    CLI_cmd_vett     = &__CLI_cmd_start;
    CLI_cmd_vett_len = (int)(&__CLI_cmd_end - &__CLI_cmd_start);
    assert((sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array)) == CLI_cmd_vett_len);
    for (int i = 0; i < CLI_cmd_vett_len; i++)
    {
        printf("%d    %p %s %p\n", i, array[i], array[i] == &CLI_cmd_vett[i] ? "==" : "!=", &CLI_cmd_vett[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

Here I used the actual structure; it doesn't matter how I initialize the constants.
In this case the 32 byte alignment returns (and the READONLY disappears)
Sections:
Idx Name               Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn  Flags
[...]
 24 .data              00000028  0000000000004000  0000000000004000  00003000  2**4  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 25 .CLI_cmd_section   000000a8  0000000000004040  0000000000004040  00003040  2**5  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 26 .bss               00000008  00000000000040e8  00000000000040e8  000030e8  2**0  ALLOC
[...]

obviously this version doesn't work (fails assert).
I also tried forcing 8 byte alignment of typedef, but nothing changes
Right now I just want to understand why with in this second case comes the 32-byte alignment, and of course how to prevent it, so that I can access the array safely.
EDIT using assembly file
As suggested by @Giackkk I tried using a simple assembly file:
cli_cmd_section.s:
.section .CLI_cmd_section, "a"

my linker script seen above (without any ALIGN statement) called cli-cmd.ld.
The example I want to compile is the second one called testAlign1.c (because testAlign.c worked out of the box).
build:
$ gcc -c cli_cmd_section.s -o cli_cmd_section.o
$ gcc -c testAlign1.c -o testAlign1.o
$ gcc testAlign1.o cli_cmd_section.o -Tcli-cmd.ld -o testAlign1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: cli_cmd_section.o: missing .note.GNU-stack section implies executable stack
/usr/bin/ld: NOTE: This behaviour is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of the linker

objdump:
$ objdump -w -h testAlign1

Sections:
Idx Name               Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn  Flags
[...]
 23 .data              00000028  0000000000004000  0000000000004000  00003000  2**4  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 24 .CLI_cmd_section   000000a8  0000000000004040  0000000000004040  00003040  2**5  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 25 .bss               00000008  00000000000040e8  00000000000040e8  000030e8  2**0  ALLOC
[...]

At the moment I run Ubuntu 23.10, and here are the version of tools:
$ uname -a
Linux jarvis 6.5.0-35-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Apr 26 11:23:57 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 13.2.0-4ubuntu3) 13.2.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

$ ld --version
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.41


For the READONLY part, have you tried to define a memory section as readonly and then place the .CLI_cmd_section in it?
https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/MEMORY.html

@Giackkk I have edited, take a look...

another way to make a section read-only is by changing the section header flags, in this case you need to ensure that in the section flags of .CLI_cmd_section the w flag is not present. https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Section.html

@Giackkk tell me more, since there is also the 'r' flag for readonly, where would you put it?

now i will add an answer but the r flag is not readonly in elf targets but in coff targets

You don't have to parse the elf binary to get ORIGIN/LENGTH if you want the address range for a section. The binary can define symbols for that, similar to _edata. For a given section, (e.g. sctname), try: extern char __start_sctname, __stop_sctname; and use the addresses of those.

Looking at the code you have added, I believe because you created multiple input sections starting with .CLI_cmd. and put them in a single output section you want to be using SUBALIGN(8)

regarding the "clean" way to impose READONLY the .CLI_cmd_section without having errors/warning from the linker part of your question, you can get it by changing the section header flags, in this case you need to ensure that in the section flags of .CLI_cmd_section the w flag is not present
from the binutils docs:

w:    section is writable


here is a simplified example on how to do it:
section.s
.section .CLI_cmd_section, "a" 
.global cli_cmd_data
cli_cmd_data:
    .ascii "Hello from assembly section\n"

in this piece of code i have added a new section with only the a flag (allocatable).
using readelf you can check the section header flags:
readelf -a main_program
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
  [ 1] .interp           PROGBITS         00000000004002a8  000002a8
       000000000000001b  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [ 2] .note.gnu.bu[...] NOTE             00000000004002c4  000002c4
       0000000000000024  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [ 3] .note.ABI-tag     NOTE             00000000004002e8  000002e8
       0000000000000020  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [ 4] .gnu.hash         GNU_HASH         0000000000400308  00000308
       000000000000001c  0000000000000000   A       5     0     8
  [ 5] .dynsym           DYNSYM           0000000000400328  00000328
       00000000000000a8  0000000000000018   A       6     1     8
  [ 6] .dynstr           STRTAB           00000000004003d0  000003d0
       0000000000000085  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [ 7] .gnu.version      VERSYM           0000000000400456  00000456
       000000000000000e  0000000000000002   A       5     0     2
  [ 8] .gnu.version_r    VERNEED          0000000000400468  00000468
       0000000000000030  0000000000000000   A       6     1     8
  [ 9] .rela.dyn         RELA             0000000000400498  00000498
       0000000000000048  0000000000000018   A       5     0     8
  [10] .rela.plt         RELA             00000000004004e0  000004e0
       0000000000000060  0000000000000018  AI       5    23     8
  [11] .init             PROGBITS         0000000000410000  00010000
       000000000000001c  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [12] .plt              PROGBITS         0000000000410020  00010020
       0000000000000060  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     16
  [13] .text             PROGBITS         0000000000410080  00010080
       000000000000017c  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     64
  [14] .fini             PROGBITS         00000000004101fc  000101fc
       0000000000000018  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [15] .rodata           PROGBITS         0000000000420000  00020000
       000000000000003d  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [16] .CLI_cmd_section  PROGBITS         000000000042003d  0002003d
       000000000000001c  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1

you can see that the only flag is a and is the same as the .rodata section.
if you want to check further, here a simple main to check that this section is readonly:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

extern const char cli_cmd_data[];

int main() {
    printf("%s", cli_cmd_data);

    // Attempt to write to the read-only section
    char *ptr = (char *)cli_cmd_data;
    strcpy(ptr, "Trying to write to read-only section");

    return 0;
}

by running it i get:
 ./main_program 
Hello from assembly section
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

SO if i add to the assembly code also the w flag, such that:
.section .CLI_cmd_section, "wa" 
.global cli_cmd_data
cli_cmd_data:
    .ascii "Hello from assembly section\n"

I can check that the flag is being added to the section header:
readelf -a main_program
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
  [ 1] .interp           PROGBITS         00000000004002a8  000002a8
       000000000000001b  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [ 2] .note.gnu.bu[...] NOTE             00000000004002c4  000002c4
       0000000000000024  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [ 3] .note.ABI-tag     NOTE             00000000004002e8  000002e8
       0000000000000020  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [ 4] .gnu.hash         GNU_HASH         0000000000400308  00000308
       000000000000001c  0000000000000000   A       5     0     8
  [ 5] .dynsym           DYNSYM           0000000000400328  00000328
       00000000000000a8  0000000000000018   A       6     1     8
  [ 6] .dynstr           STRTAB           00000000004003d0  000003d0
       0000000000000085  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [ 7] .gnu.version      VERSYM           0000000000400456  00000456
       000000000000000e  0000000000000002   A       5     0     2
  [ 8] .gnu.version_r    VERNEED          0000000000400468  00000468
       0000000000000030  0000000000000000   A       6     1     8
  [ 9] .rela.dyn         RELA             0000000000400498  00000498
       0000000000000048  0000000000000018   A       5     0     8
  [10] .rela.plt         RELA             00000000004004e0  000004e0
       0000000000000060  0000000000000018  AI       5    22     8
  [11] .init             PROGBITS         0000000000410000  00010000
       000000000000001c  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [12] .plt              PROGBITS         0000000000410020  00010020
       0000000000000060  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     16
  [13] .text             PROGBITS         0000000000410080  00010080
       000000000000017c  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     64
  [14] .fini             PROGBITS         00000000004101fc  000101fc
       0000000000000018  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [15] .rodata           PROGBITS         0000000000420000  00020000
       000000000000003d  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [16] .eh_frame_hdr     PROGBITS         0000000000420040  00020040
       0000000000000044  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [17] .eh_frame         PROGBITS         0000000000420088  00020088
       00000000000000dc  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [18] .init_array       INIT_ARRAY       000000000043fde8  0002fde8
       0000000000000008  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [19] .fini_array       FINI_ARRAY       000000000043fdf0  0002fdf0
       0000000000000008  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [20] .dynamic          DYNAMIC          000000000043fdf8  0002fdf8
       00000000000001d0  0000000000000010  WA       6     0     8
  [21] .got              PROGBITS         000000000043ffc8  0002ffc8
       0000000000000020  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [22] .got.plt          PROGBITS         000000000043ffe8  0002ffe8
       0000000000000038  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [23] .data             PROGBITS         0000000000440020  00030020
       0000000000000004  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     1
  [24] .CLI_cmd_section  PROGBITS         0000000000440024  00030024
       000000000000001c  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     1

here you can see that i have actually added the w flag so the section should not be readonly anymore.
And now running it we get.
./main_program 
Hello from assembly section

So, no more segmentation fault, thus the section with the w flag in it is writable.
Note that I cut some section headers when I copied the results of
readelf -a main_program



EDIT: to clarify this is my section.s and linker-script with your example:
section.s
.section .CLI_cmd_section, "a" 

custom.ld
SECTIONS
{
     /* section for CLI cmd array */
     .CLI_cmd_section : ALIGN(8)
    {
        PROVIDE(__CLI_cmd_start = .);
        KEEP(*(.CLI_cmd*));
        PROVIDE(__CLI_cmd_end = .);
    }
}
INSERT AFTER .data;

i compile and link it in this way:
gcc -c section.s -o section.o
gcc -c example.c -o example.o
gcc example.o section.o -T custom.ld -o example

and it works correctly.
if i check using:
readelf -a example
  [24] .CLI_cmd_section  PROGBITS         0000000000440048  00030048
   0000000000000078  0000000000000000   A       0     0   8  

here you can see that both alignment (8) and readonly (a flag) are correctly set

I tried as you say, but without adding the string. I get a warning already compiling, and then it doesn't change--the section remains writable. I've edited the post, there is some additional info, maybe you can think of an idea.

i have tried on my mac m1 asahi linux using gcc and your code works with no warnings, also if try to align it to 32 it aligns it correctly.

the code of the two tests I put in my post give no warning. But if I try as add the section.s file, as you suggested, they do.
/usr/bin/ld: warning: /tmp/ccjLvQZj.o: missing .note.GNU-stack section implies executable stack
/usr/bin/ld: NOTE: This behaviour is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of the linker
Instead, when you say you aligned to 32 byte what are you referring to?

i am referring to the fact that if i set a custom alignment to the section for example: ALIGN(8) or ALIGN(32) it aligns it correctly.

seen. I edited my post too, so you can see what happens to me, also you see the versions of the tools.

GNU ld version 2.40-14.fc39
try downgrading ld to this(at least this version works for me)
